# find all integer $(x,y)$ solutions to: $x^2 \leq y \leq x+6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Problem: find all integer $(x,y)$ solutions to: $x^2 \leq y \leq x+6$

I have found the solutions to this by graphing and it turns out there are $26$ integer solutions but I am wondering if there is a way to find the solution without using the graphing method. Could anyone assist on how to solve this without using graphing?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For $y$ to be wedged between $x^2$ (below) and $x+6$ (above), we must have $x^2\le x+6$ to start with. This is true only for a finite set of integral $x$'s: $-2\le x\le 3$. This gives you six candidates for $x$: $-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3$. For each of them, calculate $x^2$ and $x+6$ and find integer $y$'s in that range.

Comment: $-3 + 6 < (-3)^2,~$ and this inequality persists for $x < -3$.  Also,   $4 + 6 < 4^2, ~$ and this inequality persists for $x > 4.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stinking Bishop pointed out in the comments, $x$ must satisfy the constraint.

$$x^2 \le x + 6$$
$$x^2 - x - 6 \le 0$$
$$(x + 2)(x - 3) \le 0$$
$$-2 \le x \le 3$$

There are only 6 integers in this range (including the endpoints), so we can easily just brute-force it:

| x | x^2 | x + 6 | possible y values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -2 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| -1 | 1 | 5 | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 |
| 0 | 0 | 6 | 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 | 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 |
| 3 | 9 | 9 | 9 |